# about firewall setting in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

setting up the server in AWS.
fix some options in firewall of control pannel.
shortly after, I want to back original setting, setting up firewall default.
and then It's blocked. 
I could not access the computer using remote. 
I think the problem is port.
there are some the other way can access the AWS or fix the firewall in website ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking
Do you still have access to the AWS Management console? Can you SSH into the server? What server is it? (Windows / Linux?)

If you do have access to AWS Management console go into the firewall settings and allow the ports you need (typically its at a minimum, TCP 80 (http for web pages) TCP 22 (For SSH login) TCP 25 (if you're running a mail server).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it (and unless they've changed it) once you assign a security group, you can't change it, so you either have to edit the security group settings or you have to destroy and create a new image where you are allowed to create/set a new security group.

You may need to restart the computer after you've changed / enabled the ports on the security group as your machine's software may have not been able to bind to particular ports on startup.